# Why is the polymorphic weight 1

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus, type-inference

I am reading through through a paper called [HMF: Simple Type Inference for First-Class Polymorphism](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/132621/hmf.pdf) by Daan Leijen of Microsoft Research.

In the paper it describes how to calculate the polymorphic weight of an expression:

[image: extract from pdf]

I am having trouble understanding why the above example `[[forall a. [forall b. a -> b]]]` has a weight of 1 rather than two. there are two type abstractions where both type variable are not free in their bodies, should these not be added together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked why

> `[[forall a. [forall b. a -> b]]]` has a weight of 1

It doesn't. It has a *polymorphic* weight of 1. The polymorphic weight strips the binder before it looks at the weight. For the $\rho$ you chose:

$[\![\forall \overline{\alpha} . \rho]\!] = wt(\rho) = 1 \neq 2 = wt(\forall \overline{\alpha} . \rho)$